# Why is my electric hot water heater producing lukewarm/cold water?

Tags: electrical, water-heater

Yesterday after returning home from work I discovered my hot water is not working. When you turn on the faucet (any in the house) just a little warm water comes out and then it turns cold. I checked the fusebox. It was not tripped. I'm going to buy a multimeter today to test the fusebox. Please, any help or suggestions as to what I should do???

Comment: Could you give more information about the type of hot water system? All electric? Gas? Oil? Separate or part of an heating system?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the answers on this question - http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9105/why-is-my-hot-water-running-out-quickly-regardless-of-other-household-water-usag - cover the common issues with electric hot water heaters.

Comment: It is all electric. Its not part of the heating system for the rest of the home. Its a relatively small condo (900 sqft) with 1 bathroom. so its only supplying the bathroom and kitchen ....any input would be great....thanks in advance...

Comment: A water heater takes cold water and attempts to make hot water. We could also call that a cold water heater. What does a hot water heater produce? Steam?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the first bit of lukewarm water is just what is in the plumbing. It's warmed up by the air in your home as it sits there. The cold water after is what's sitting in the hot water heater.

With that in mind, it looks like your hot water heater is not working at all.

Comment: Thanks Jay...@Bib I added more info....If you could shed some light... Thanks